# LWJGL: Pixel Format Not Accelerated

Tags: java, windows-10, slick2d

I'm using Windows 10 and have been able to run LWGJL code while using Windows 10. I have an Intel HD Family Graphics 3000 running the latest driver. I'm developing a game and am using Slick2D. Recently, I have been unable to run my application because java errors and tells me that the LWJGL pixel format is not accelerated. The catch is that I have create a Windows 10 virtual machine and installed JDK 8u60 x64 and have been able to execute code with Slick2D and render perfectly fine. My graphics drivers are **up to date**. Just to reiterate I have been able to in the past use LWJGL code and Windows 10 together and they worked perfectly fine. Also, Minecraft **does** work. Does anyone have any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is an undocumented bug with JDK 8u60 and above. Try to use JDK 8u51.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue, fixed with 8u45.